# SQL Server How to SELECT a column only if it exists in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case, union

I would like to execute a SELECT, where it selects a column-value only if that column exists in the table, else display null.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
SELECT TOP 10 CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='test' and TABLE_NAME='tableName' and COLUMN_NAME='columnName') 
THEN columnName ELSE NULL END AS columnName
```

I also tried this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 CASE WHEN 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='test' and TABLE_NAME='tableName' and COLUMN_NAME='columnName') >0 
THEN columnName ELSE NULL END AS columnName
```

Both of them work well if the column is present in the table. But when the column is not present, it gives me the error :

*Invalid column name 'columnName'*

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL. For any particular query, the tables and columns that it will access is fixed, and the query won't even start executing and retrieving data (which it would need to in your attempts) if it cannot compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write as:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='test' and TABLE_NAME='tableName' 
    and COLUMN_NAME='columnName'
) 
THEN
(
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='test' and TABLE_NAME='tableName'
    and COLUMN_NAME='columnName'
)
ELSE
NULL 
END
AS columnName
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/TMGRA53150)</kbd>

Edit:
If you are looking to select top 10 values from a table's column if that column exists then you need to write a dynamic query as:

```
SELECT @columnVariable =     
CASE WHEN EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='test' and TABLE_NAME='tableName' 
    and COLUMN_NAME='columnName'
) 
THEN
(
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='test' and TABLE_NAME='tableName' 
    and COLUMN_NAME='columnName'
)
ELSE
NULL 
END


/* Build the SQL string one time.*/
SET @SQLString =
     N'SELECT TOP 10 ' + @columnVariable+ '
       FROM test.tableName ';      


EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```

<kbd>[DEMO2](http://rextester.com/BKP30566)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1
        CASE 
            WHEN COLUMN_NAME='columnName' THEN 
                COLUMN_NAME 
            ELSE 
                NULL 
            END 
        AS COLUMN_NAME
FROM        
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA ='test' and TABLE_NAME='tableName'
ORDER BY
    COLUMN_NAME DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
        FROM sys.columns
        WHERE [name] = N'columnName'
            AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tableName')
```

Add this inside your case statement. Please note that this code would work only for higher version of sqlserver.[like sqlserver 2008]